# How do I pass a variable to a varchar declaration?

Tags: mysql

Extremely simple question. I need to alter a bunch of tables in a DB to add a new column. This is my code:

```
# the maximum character length we allow for chat is 14
SET @maxlen = 14;

alter table tbl1 add chat varchar(@maxlen);
alter table tbl2 add chat varchar(@maxlen);
alter table tbl3 add chat varchar(@maxlen);
alter table tbl4 add chat varchar(@maxlen);
alter table tbl5 add chat varchar(@maxlen);
```

I get the error: 
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'maxlen)' at line 1`

It says line 1 in the error code, but the error is happening in line 5, which is the first alter statement. How can I do what I'm looking to do here?

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for requires dynamic SQL.

Consider:

```
set @maxlen = 14;
set @sql = concat('alter table tbl1 add chat varchar(', @maxlen, ')');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Comment: Are for loops and stuff allowed in sql? I guess I need a list of the tables and then a for loop to go through that list and execute each sql statement